# People Column (Allow Multiple Selections) in HTMLText Control

Tags: sharepoint, office365, ms-office, powerapps

I am creating an HTMLText form so that I could integrate my form with MS Flow to allow my form to be printable.

However, the Stakeholders variable does not work because I think it is treated as an array instead of Text. My other people columns worked fine but that's because it only allowed single selection.

I tried using the ClearCollect, Collect, and Listbox Control but none seem to work

The prompt always says "Invalid Argument: Expecting Text..."

Answer (score 0):

Even though you've set the ComboBox to allow only one selection, you will still need to specify that only the first selected item is passed in.

Syntax is:

```
First(COMBOBOX_NAME.SelectedItems).FieldName
```